# Vertical line left out in tabular

Tags: tables, multicolumn, rules, vertical

The code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
  \hline
  \multirow{2}{*}{Color Type} & \multirow{2}{*}{Channels} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Bits per
    channel} \\    
  \cline{3-7}
  & & 1 & 2 & 4 & 8 & 16 \\    
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Results in the table

[image]

How may I fix this code so that a vertical line is also added after "Bits per channel"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is as simple as the notation of the column is overwritten by `\multicolumn{5}{c}`. 
Try instead: `\multicolumn{5}{c|}{Bits per channel}`.