# Missing lines in Multi-Column Table

Tags: tables, multicolumn

So I have a table which uses multi-column headers and it seems to work great except for one thing. When I render the document, there are some missing vertical lines in the table header and I can't figure out why they are missing. My code:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c : c | c : c : c |}
    \hline
    Input & Stage 1 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Stage 2} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Stage 3} \\ 
    \hline
    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 2 & 2 \\
    7 & 7 & 7 & 5 & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
    5 & 5 & 5 & 7 & 2 & 4 & 4 \\
    3 & 3 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 5 & 5 \\
    6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 \\
    8 & 8 & 3 & 3 & 5 & 8 & 7 \\
    2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 7 & 7 & 8 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

I'm using the tabularx package and arydshln for the dotted lines.

When I render it it looks like this:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: you need to add the vertical lines inside `\multicolumn`, like this: `\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Stage 2} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Stage 3}` The tabular layout is superseded by the multicolumn specs. See for example: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42045/vertical-line-left-out-in-tabular

Comment: For your final header entry, use `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{..}`.

Comment: Thanks guys. @dcmst, if you wanna put that as an actual answer I'll accept it.

Comment: You're welcome. There's no need to answer, I assume this will be closed as duplicate soon.